# Wondering about scope in C++ with structures and functions

Tags: c++, function, scope

I'm writing a program that allows me to put my name in and pull up different semesters and for me to put grades in and then be able to calculate my class average and GPA, just for my own reference in my courses.

What I am having a problem with is with structures and how they work with a multifunction program. In my courses we have not covered this and I have spent a while now searching for answers and cannot find one. Below is my current code:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char gettingName();

class Student{
    public:
        double semesterClass[20][20];       //first is for semester, second is for which class
        char name[20];
        int semester;
        int numOfCourses;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Student info;
    gettingName();
    cout << "Hi my name is: " << name.info << endl;
    return 0;
}

char gettingName()
{
    Student info;

    char YesNo[5];
    char boolean[1] = {'T'};
    char yes[3] = {'Y','e','s'};
    char yes2[3] = {'Y','E','S'};
    char yes3[3] = {'y','e','s'};
    char yes4[1] = {'Y'};
    char yes5[1] = {'y'};
    while(boolean[0] == 'T'){
        cout << "What is your name? ";
        cin >> info.name;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Is your name " << info.name << "?"<<endl;  //accepted input will be Y,y,YES,Yes,yes
        cin >> YesNo;
    //if input does not equal any of the accepted inputs, then loop until it does
        if((strcmp(YesNo,yes) == 0) || (strcmp(YesNo,yes2) == 0) || (strcmp(YesNo,yes3) == 0) || (YesNo[0] == yes4[0]) || (YesNo[0] == yes5[0])){
        boolean[0] = 'F';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question: how might I go about fixing the scope so that I can call the 'gettingName' function, get the person to input their name, (get it right (that already works)) and then be able to access and print it in the main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code, but I will try to help out the best I can. In general C++ scope for local variables is at the block level. So any time you see a ending bracket }, the scope has ended.

Some specific issues with your code that I noticed:

- This line should be: "cout << "Hi my name is: " << **info.name** <<
  endl;", not name.info
- The boolean loop can be handled much more efficiently. You should try to list all of the acceptable options in one data structure like an array and then loop through the array.
- Lastly when creating a function that doesn't need to return anything,
  you can use the type void instead of char. So it could be void gettingName(), instead of char gettingName().

As an example to show you a quick and easy way to do what I think you wanted, I simplified your code a bit. I also decided to use std::string rather than char arrays as they are easier to work with:

```
class Student{
public:
    std::string name;
};

std::string gettingName();

int main()
{
  Student Info;
  Info.name = gettingName();
  cout << "Hi my name is: " << Info.name << endl;
  return 0;
}

std::string gettingName()
{
  std::string name;
  cout << "What is your name? ";
  cin >> name;
  cout << endl;
  return name;
}
```

Comment: Alright...I see the logic in your code and it makes sense. I'm a little confused on the whole 'public:    std::string name;'.
What does that do? Does it create an array so that it is easier to pass between functions? (Because I was have had trouble in the past trying to pass whole strings instead of just chars). Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question is: What does the std::string do?

Comment: Ahhh ok. So you are just declaring a whole string at a time. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code not really is object oriented. To fix the scope, you'll have to put `gettingName` inside your class to make it a *member function* (which is btw the term to Google for). You will also have to change the implementation which then needs to include the class name for identification:

```
char Student::gettingName()
{
    ...
}
```

From `main` you'd call it then via

```
info.gettingName();
```

Comment: Thank you. I am researching member function right now.
One more quick question, what does the :: do? Or does it have a name I can research? Thanks again!

Comment: It certainly is C++, just not object oriented. Claiming otherwise is a cargo cult argument.

Comment: Found the name for _::_ for anyone that stumbles upon this and wonders, its a _scope resolution operator_.
Thanks again!